# Find the largest positive integer $d$ with a certain property.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

Find the largest positive integer $d$ with a property, that for any positive integer $n$ the value of expression $V(n) = n^4+11n^2-12$ is a multiple of $d$.

Could somebody give me a hint on how to start solving this problem?

Comment: compute $ V(2) $ and see.

Comment: How will that exact value help me?

Comment: The divisors of $ V(2) $ are the possible values of $ d$.

Comment: I understand, but can I find out the largest possible value of $d$ without computing $V(n)$ for n > 2?

Comment: So we are looking for the greatest common divisor of $V(1), V(2), V(3), \ldots$. This must be a divisor of $V(2), V(3), \ldots$. If you compute a few of these smaller values, you can make a hypothesis on what $d$ is, and then prove it using modular arithmetic, number theory, maybe even induction not sure.

Comment: The number $d$ certainly divides $V(2)$, so you can compute it and already find that there are only a finite number of possible $d$'s.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I don't think that claim is true. Just because $5$ is not a divisor of $V(5)$ doesn't mean that $6$ cannot be. We don't need to find the largest $d$ such that all integers below it divide $V(n)$.

Comment: $$n^4+11n^2-12=(n^2-1)(n^2+12)$$

Comment: The same methods in the linked dupe apply here.

Comment: This question was improperly closed. The question linked *looks* similar but is actually not.

Comment: @Mike Please read the prior comment.

Answer (score -1):

Note that we may verify that for any $d$ we have

$$V(n+d)\equiv V(n)\ (\text{mod }d)$$

Thus, in order to check that a particular $d$ has the desired property, it is sufficient to check the integers $\{0,1,...,d-1\}$. As a hint on how to continue, note that $d$ divides $V(2)=48=2^4\cdot 3$ (as pointed out by @hamam_Abdallah). Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand the expression you wrote.

Comment: @badatmath The expression basically means is that let's say you think a certain $d$ satisfies the required properties. Then you simply need to prove that $d|V(n)$ for all $n\in\{0,1,\ldots d-1\}$.